# VisualStudion and TFS: go to previous version by Changeset ID, back and forth

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am much more used to SVN than to TFS so I am unsure on how to do this. 
I have some project that use to be fast in some data around 10 days ago and now I tested it again on that data and it is much slower. So I would like to go to each of the versions of the entire project (not just a file) between 10 days ago and now, without losing any version.
So basically: how do I checkout some version by Changeset number, run it, then checkout another one and so forth without ever loosing any of the versions? Specifically, every time I go to previous version I may want to change stuff in the code (for testing further) and I want this changes to be lost every time I checkout another version (because I don't want them to remain anywhere).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Source Control Explorer, right click on a folder and choose *Get Specific Version*. It's under an "Advanced" menu, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I saw this, but I was a bit afraid of doing it in case I lose the latest versions (it has happened to me before in Git...). If I "Go to specific version", all the later versions remain there? And if I "Go to specific version", I make some changes, and then try to go to some other version, will the changes made block me from moving versions? Thanks

Comment: If you have changes that aren't checked in, this will overwrite them. Otherwise, it has no bearing on your source control's history.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work well. Also, on the command line this seems to work: tf get . /v:C37182   ("." because I am in the same folder where I want the changes, and C because I am providing a changeset number)